# SVN-error: Access to 'x' forbidden

Tags: svn

I'm using svn for the first time.
Three weeks ago it worked fine to commit files, now I get
Access to 'X' forbidden

Before I saw this I created a new folder and did a SVN Checkout. It worked fine.
So I have two folders with the very same project:
`C:\Projects\ProjectX`
and
`C:\Projects\ProjectX_new`

Still working with `ProjectX` (and not the new one) I did a "Revert to this revision".
And the above error showed up when I committed this Revert.

This error, could it be because of my new folder?

Should I read and follow this:
http://techo.luefher.com/other-tech/source-version-control/subversion-tortoise-svn/subversion-error-access-to-svn-my-repo-name-svn-act-some-guid-forbidden-when-trying-to-commit/

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with your new checkout folder. When it references 'X' is it a local or remote resource?

Comment: Hi 
It is a remote resource. If I untick "Enable proxy server", I get "Unable to connect to a repository at URL [url] OPTIONS of [url]".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you use correct URL. URLs in Apache Subversion are case-sensitive.
2. Make sure your system administrator hasn't provided you with No Access permission to the repository path.
3. Read [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/index.html) about [path-based authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).
4. Read [VisualSVN Team's article](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/) about path-based authorization. It explains the principles of SVN authorization by comparing it with Windows Access Control.

Comment: It was #2. I emailed admin before posting here, now I got the answer.
But I had do whatever I could from my side. Thanks for your assistance.........

Comment: Also make sure your fire wall is not interrupting your SVN checkout: Response denied by WatchGuard HTTP Proxy. Reason: body content-type denied rule='Windows EXE/DLL'