# Access to '/SVN/[repo name]/!svn/me' forbidden

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I am having some issue with some SVN users where they get the following message

> Access to '/SVN/[repo name]/!svn/me' forbidden

I am having some issues figuring out the root cause of it.

The current setup is using Visual SVN on windows.  We are using SVN security for the users, not AD.  The users are that are having some issue are vendors(but not all of them), so they do have different permissions then an average user.  But the weird thing is, I shadowed the user using Live meeting.  They try to commit and get the message above. I clear their credentials from Tortoise SVN and use mine and everything is fine.  The user is logged into the server as themselves and using my user info for SVN.  But their is no link between the SVN users and windows users.  Also the user was initially able to commit new files. I looked through SVN and I dont see anything wrong.  Any ideas?  Anyway to get more information about what is wrong.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16415743/761095 and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16287209/761095 and this http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00033/

Comment: I have looked at that issue.  and the reason I think it different is when I clear the security data and use my credentials, it is fine.

Comment: Try this   http://stackoverflow.com/a/43204615/5466401

Comment: https://github.com/10up/action-wordpress-plugin-deploy/issues/33

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, bahrep was correct that the url had an issue since it was case-sensitive.  I am confused why when I cleared the credentials and put in my how the url was corrected.

I was able to correct the URL in TortoiseSVN, by:

1. right-clicking on the Repository location
2. Selecting TortoiseSVN --> Relocate
3. Correct the url and Click Relocate

Comment: In a HTTP URL, the machine name and the `HTTP` are not case sensitive. Everything else is. If you use LDAP, it's only looking at the name of the Subversion instance (which may include multiple repos). Thus, your credentials can work if just enough of the URL is correct for Apache to apply the credentials. LDAP credentials are not case sensitive.

Answer (score 6):

Using **OS X** and **svn** command line, I get this error when I checkout another application from the same server with *another* username.

My solution is to clear the credential. The key point is to find where credential information is located. Run `svn auth` to can see the detail.  In my case, it is located at `/Users/joy.zhu/.subversion/auth/svn.simple`. There is cache file, just remove it.

Update (Or commit...) again, username/password are asked, then you can enter the correct data. Everything goes well then.

Answer (score 5):

H20rider

Please make sure the SVN url is correct. SVN is case sensitive. If you defined you root folder as ServicesTrunk then your svn access url needs to be of the same case.

you get the following error if you use

```
host:port/svn/ServicesTrunk ------- this will work

**case not right**
host:port/svn/servicesTrunk -------- will throw !svn/me' forbidden
host:port/svn/Servicestrunk --------- will throw !svn/me' forbidden
```

Comment: Yes. this was the case.  At first I didnt think this made sense since I was able to retrieve the repo without an issue.  Not sure why it would be different for updating vs committing.

Answer (score 3):

In my case i was getting the same "Access Denied.." message and my repository URL was correct.

This worked out for me

1. Go to Window in eclipse
2. Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN
3. Check whether all your svn preferences are set properly.(I changed SVN interface client from JavaHL(JNI)1.8.14(r1692801) *to* SVNKit (Pure Java) SVNKit v1.8.11.10483)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxCKC.png)

Answer (score 3):

Check authentication data.

In TortoiseSVN: settings\Saved Data\Authentication Data\Clear...

Perhaps you have more than one user/pass

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case problem was in svnaccess.txt file with define permission. Name of groups cannot have spaces e.g

```
[svnloop:/test group]
@admins = rw
```

return this erro
You must change to

```
[svnloop:/testgroup]
@admins = rw
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the reason wasn't URL case-sensitivity but **http** vs. **https**.
The solution was to relocate from

```
http://svn.code.sf.net/...
```

to

```
https://svn.code.sf.net/...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the similar problem(in windows os), and share my solution here.

problem:

```
Access to '/svn/project01/!svn/rvr/18022/trunk' forbidden
```

solution:

1. Find the root directory of the project01 repository, if you are in the d:\svn\repproject01
2. Modify VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini file
3. Delete the configuration block similar to the following

   ```
   [/xxx]
   user01=
   ```
4. run `services.msc` Restart SVN service

Comment: 1. There is no need to restart the services. 2. **DO NOT MODIFY AUTHORIZATION FILES MANUALLY!** Use VisualSVN Server PowerShell to manage access rules: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/